# getBaseContext() undefined how to solve without extension

Tags: android, extension-methods, restart, android-context

This code should restart my app:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
getContext().startActivity(i);
```

but I get a massege `getBaseContext() is undefined for the type ButtonView.PhoneCallListener`
how can I sove that without changing the extention's?

I tried `getContext()` instead but that got me to the main screen and not to the app.

Comment: Can you put class statement here, so we can see what you are extending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you obviously need is the application's context. This can be obtained via the `Context.getApplicationContext()` method. And you can obtain a Context instance via `View.getContext()`.

To put it in a nutshell, you can have access to application's context from the view code with:

```
getContext().getApplicationContext();
```

So this may work:

```
Context appContext = getContext().getApplicationContext();
Intent i = appContext .getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(appContext .getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
getContext().startActivity(i);
```

Comment: it's working ! 
I tried getApplicationContext();
and getContext()
but did thout use them tugether 
thanks for the quick unswer man !

Comment: @igor: dont forget to mark it as answer. fiddler: Can you please provide some description about why ou have used getContext() and getApplicationContext() both. It would be helpfull.

Comment: i write that: 
Intent i = getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 getContext().startActivity(i);

but i got steel to the main scean